# What is "x-apple-ql-id://*"?

Tags: macos

I have a process called `x-apple-ql-id://*` (* being a bunch of letters, numbers and "-"). Is this a legitimate process? I am wondering because it looks very fishy.

Answer (score 1):

That seems to be a legitimate process. It's a schema that belongs to [QuickLook](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/Printing/Printing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH12-SW20), but Apple doesn't have much information freely available about it. I don't think is a reason to be alarmed, just kill the process (but save your work before, just in case).

Comment: I also found QuickLook information when googling, but it was weird that there were so few results.